# Remove bold text

Tags: asciidoc

This code :

```
[cols="h,h,h,h"]
|===
|Cell in column 1, row 1
|Cell in column 2, row 1
|Cell in column 3, row 1
|Cell in column 4, row 1

|Cell in column 1, row 2
|Cell in column 2, row 2
|Cell in column 3, row 2
|Cell in column 4, row 2
|===
```

renders :

[image]

How can I render the cells with values

> Cell in column 2, row 2
>
> Cell in column 3, row 2
>
> Cell in column 4, row 2

To have non bold formatting and with white background ?

I'm attempting to have 1'st column and 1'st row with bold and background but reading https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#tables this is the closest I've got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `cols` definition says that you have 4 columns, all styled as headers.

Change that line to read:

```
[cols="a,a,a,a", options="header"]
```

The `a`'s indicate that each column can contain Asciidoc markup (instead of just being plain text). The `options="header"` causes the first row to be rendered as the header line. With that, your first row should be in bold, and any subsequent rows should be in regular weight.

Comment: thanks but as in my question 'How can I render the cells with values

Cell in column 2, row 2

Cell in column 3, row 2

Cell in column 4, row 2

To have non bold formatting and with white background ? '

I also require the first column (in addition to the first row) to also be bold.

Comment: If you continue to use `h` for the column style, all text in the table will be boldfaced. If you switch to using `a` for the style, you can selectively make text boldface wherever you need it by surrounding it with asterisks.

There is no easy way to make cell-specific background colors, especially not without modifying the CSS styles in use.